# How to remove debug code with Google Closure API?

Tags: javascript, google-closure-compiler

[The Google Closure documentation](https://developers.google.com/closure/compiler/docs/js-for-compiler) (look for `ENABLE_DEBUG` var) explains how I can change the variable by passing the flag define `--define='ENABLE_DEBUG=false'` to the compiler. `define` option is not supported by Google Closure API. At the same time, [the wiki](https://github.com/google/closure-compiler/wiki/Additional-Webservice-Options) says that `debug` option is supported by the REST service (and API?). But how can it be used in the code? Creation of according variable doesn't help, it remains unchanged:

```
/** @define {boolean} */
var debug = true;
```

Answer (score 1):

Example of what you can do :

```
/** @define {boolean} */
var MY_DEBUG = false;

if (MY_DEBUG){
    debuga = function(myparam, myparam2){
        console.log(myparam, myparam2);
        // Big debug stuff..
    };
    debugb = function(myparam, myparam2){
        console.log(myparam, myparam2);
        // Big debug stuff..
    };
}
else{
    debuga = function(myparam, myparam2){};
    debugb = function(myparam, myparam2){};
}

debuga("Hello","World");
```

You can control the value of `MY_DEBUG` with the define `--define='MY_DEBUG=false'`

It will result as something like this

```
// SIMPLE_OPTIMIZATION            // ADVANCED_OPTIMIZATION
var DEBUG=!1;                     debuga=function(){};
debuga=function(a,b){};           debugb=function(){};
debugb=function(a,b){};           debuga("Hello","World");
debuga("Hello","World");
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the Closure Library support you can include a definition of CLOSURE_DEFINES along with the reset of the source that you send to the compiler.

To see this in action, you can do the following:

http://closure-compiler.appspot.com/home

```
// ==ClosureCompiler==
// @compilation_level ADVANCED_OPTIMIZATIONS
// @output_file_name default.js
// @use_closure_library true
// ==/ClosureCompiler==

var CLOSURE_DEFINES = {
  'FOO' : true
}

/** @define {boolean} */
var FOO = false;
if (FOO) {
  alert('me');
}
```

This results in:

```
alert("me");
```

Comment: Thanks. Looks like it works. But (1) I don't use the Closure Library. If I use it, then the file size increases significantly. (2) I don't see what could be the reason to use it in the way you've describe - in result I should modify `FOO` variable in the same file where original `FOO` is defined.

Comment: (1) I assume you are using SIMPLE mode. In ADVANCED mode, the increase cause by including Closure's "base.js" is 0 bytes. (2) If you are willing to modify the file, then you don't need @define.  Otherwise, using a bit of shell script to build or swap configuration files seems easy enough and not much harder than putting "--define='Foo=X'" somewhere.